# Unable to create view to materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, view, materialized-views

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TESTING_MVIEW
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST
AS

SELECT PROJECT_ID,PROJECT_NUMBER, PROJECT_NAME, TASK_ID, TASK_NUMBER,GL_ACCOUNT,GL_DEPARTMENT,EXPENDITURE_ORG,ACCOUNT_DESC,GL_PERIOD_NAME,
EXPENDITURE_TYPE,EXPENDITURE_CATEGORY, EXPENDITURE_ITEM_DATE,QUANTITY,AMOUNT,EXPENDITURE_GROUP,SERVICE_TYPE_CODE,SERVICE_TYPE_MEANING,
COST_TYPE, PEI_LAST_UPDATE_DATE,EXPENDITURE_ITEM_ID 
FROM APPS.XXCCIPA_WPROJECTS_ACTUALS_V;



Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: The error says that `APPS.XXCCIPA_WPROJECTS_ACTUALS_V` doesn't exist. Further, if you already have all the fields in an existing table/view - why create a new one? Furthermore, what's the added value of creating a materialized view if you want to refresh it upon every call?

Comment: @NirAlfasi I'm able to query APPS.XXCCIPA_WPROJECTS_ACTUALS_V and its taking long time to return the data so planning to create materialized view for it. NOTE : This is the first time im working on materialized view

Comment: Have you tried to just use the query you use for the view for the materialized view?

Comment: Yes i did, We have subquery in view so its returning below errorError report -
ORA-22818: subquery expressions not allowed here
22818. 00000 -  "subquery expressions not allowed here"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to use a subquery expression where these
           are not supported.
*Action:   Rewrite the statement without the subquery expression.

Comment: That last error occurs when you try to include a subquery in a GROUP BY clause, which is probably what you're doing in that view.

Comment: But you're mixing different problems here: "table or view does not exist" is very straightforward!

Comment: Further, you do understand that the information in a MATERIALIZED VIEW should actively get refreshed every now and then otherwise it becomes stale, right?